# Error while passing series of numbers as a parameter to a JavaScript function in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Here's my PHP code -

```
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
   $numbers .= $i."\n";
}
echo "<input type='button' onclick=ShowNumbers('$numbers') value='Show Numbers'>";
```

And my Javascript code -

```
function ShowNumbers(numbers)
{
   alert("Numbers:: "+numbers);
}
```

But when I click on the button **Show Numbers**, nothing happens. Whats going wrong ?

When in FireBug I check the button element it shows -

```
<input type="button" value="Show Numbers" ');="" 10="" 9="" 8="" 7="" 6="" 5="" 4="" 3="" 2="" onclick="ShowNumbers('1">
```

may be thats where the problem lies. How do I get it in right format?

Comment: From experience, I suspect that putting linebreak "\n" characters inside the onclick attribute is probably not a good idea. I would also recommend nesting your call to ShowNumbers in quotes for good measure. What happens if you change the deliminating character to a comma instead of a newline?

Comment: @DokktorRavenstein Above is just a simplified version of a rather complicated code. Actually in my project, instead of 'numbers', there's gonna be content that needs to be exported to Excel format. So really cant think of replacing newline with any other character

Comment: If you have control over the destination JavaScript function, [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) can be a very quick way to translate a PHP variable into something that's JavaScript-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the way you format the parameters.  If you look at the page source in the browser, then you'll see the line breaks inside the parameters.  If you want to have the message box display all the numbers, you can try doing this:

```
$numbers = ""
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
   $numbers .= "$i\\n";
}
echo "<input type='button' onclick=\"ShowNumbers('$numbers')\" value='Show Numbers'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes when you're building your HTML:

```
echo '<input type="button" onclick="ShowNumbers(\'' . $numbers . '\')" value="Show Numbers">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to surround the onClick attribute value with double quotes, like your other attributes.:

```
onclick="ShowNumbers('$numbers')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
   $numbers .= $i . ",";
}
echo "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"ShowNumbers('" . $numbers . "')\" value=\"Show Numbers\" />";
```

with;

```
function ShowNumbers(numbers)
{
   alert("Numbers = " + numbers);
}
```

It should render as;

```
<input type="button" onclick="ShowNumbers('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,')" value="Show Numbers" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quotes. When using PHP and HTML you should echo using single quotes so you can use double quotes inside your string like this:

```
echo '<input type="button" onclick="ShowNumbers(\'' . $numbers . '\')" value="Show Numbers" />';
```

Also, it would be better to leave the carriage return out of the `$numbers` variable and format it when you print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowNumbers(numbers){
alert(numbers);
}

</script>   

<head>    
<body>

<?php
$numbers='';
for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
   $numbers .= $i;
}
echo "<input type='button' onclick='ShowNumbers($numbers)' value='Show Numbers'>";

?>    
</body>
</html>
```